# scheduleAtFixedRate slow / late

Tags: java, timing, executorservice

I'm using a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to provide an update to a database every hour with the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method.  The problem is that it gradually gets later - in long service I've been logging it and it's about a second a day.

I made a small class just to examine this aspect - seems to work fine when nothing is happening on the PC ( running WinXP ) but if things are going on it rapidly gets later.  `18:00:00.5` last night was its first log and this morning was `09:00:00.5` then `10:00:05.9`, `11:00:26.8`, `12:00:45.3`, `13:01:07.8`...

I can attach the code although my example isn't the smallest.

Anyone else experienced this?  Any ideas why this isn't working properly?

I can think of lots of ways around it but I'd really like to know why it doesn't work as advertised!

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 2):

This is normal AFAIK. With [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29), If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late. That being said, I'd recommend [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). This will ensure that tasks are carried out at the specified delay interval.

Comment: No, the duration of each execution should not matter, according to the JavaDoc: `In the long run, the frequency of execution will be exactly the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system clock underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).`

Comment: @Thomas, Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Moonbean I just figured I got the wrong class - `Timer` instead of `ScheduledExecutorService`. However, the JavaDoc you linked states your answer the other way round: `scheduleAtFixedRate` should start exactly at `initial_delay + n * rate` whereas `scheduleWithFixedDelay` would take the duration of the task into account: `...with the given delay between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the next` (scheduleWithFixedDelay)

Comment: @Thomas, Did you read my answer? If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late. So, a fixed interval is not always possible with `scheduleAtFixedRate`. With `scheduleWithFixedDelay`, subsequent tasks will always still start at the specified interval, regardless of task execution time.

Comment: You're right, that's what `scheduleAtFixedRate` would do, sorry for misreading. However, I'd still rather use that instead of `scheduleWithFixedDelay`, since the OP wants execution to be as close to the full hour as possible. Additionally, I'd doubt the update would take exactly one hour and a few seconds but that should be verified - @Michael please tell us :)

Comment: "If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late" - my task does not take longer than an hour - in my test class it takes about 50 ms to write a 5 MB file ;-)  As pointed out above, the JavaDoc says "executions will commence after initialDelay then initialDelay+period, then initialDelay + 2 * period, and so on" i.e. with a period of 3600000 ms you'd expect it to kick off every hour, even if occasionally it is kicked off track because Windows is busy doing something else.

Comment: Well this is interesting... since 2 o'clock that afternoon ( just after I first posted! ) the process was kicked off early!  It went from 13:01:07.8 to 13:59:59 and is now about 1.5 s early e.g. the last log was 08:59:58.6.  I haven't looked at the source for this class - does anyone know it and if so is this expected behaviour to try to average out the start point?  Another factor is that there was a lot of activity on the test PC yesterday and yet the start time was steadfastly constant.